# How do I imitate the Jest describe it pattern?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

How do I write the `login` and `get` functions in javascript? I have a feeling that it's possible with some mixture of inline functions, bind and this magic. Or is it impossible?

```js
Promise.all([
  login("user1", () => {
    console.log(get("/healthy")); // prints "user1/healthy"
  }),
  login("user2", () => {
    console.log(get("/ready")); // prints "user2/ready"
  })
]);
```

I know it would be possible to write it like this. But I got curious about writing it without the obj.

```
login("user1", (obj) => {
  obj.get("/ready");
});
```

Isn't this similar to how Jest have coded the descript/it pattern?

```
describe("Login test", () => {
  test("Login", async () => {
    expect("ready").toEqual("ready");
  });
});
```

Comment: This is not exactly what Jest does, but it does this by polluting global namespace, which is usually not something you want to do in an app. It's possible to skip object name like you want with "with" keyword, and you certainly don't want to do that because it's deprecated. It's unclear where does obj comes from in your case.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The reason i want this: I have a kind of import script that works with lots of. get, post and patch function invocations.They are all sharing the same axios instance. It works fine to run asyncrounous. But then I added login functionality and wanted different login "contexts" to use it's own instance of axios. At the same time I wanted to keep the old clean look of the import scripts (without obj.get). And I had the feeling it was possible. But now I have my doubts and the reason has changed to a quest to find out what's possible in javascript.

Comment: Jest is only able to do this because it runs the tests in serial. So they are able to assign to test (or any other local variable) knowing that it won't be used in two different tests at the same time.  In your example, you want to be logged in as two different users in parallel, so you are going to need that `obj` to keep track of the two contexts. It's an interesting question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can technically make it work, but I don't recommend for reasons I'll explain later.

Here is a working example with the `get` function as a local variable.  We assign to this `get` variable immediately before the callback is called.
It holds the login context in its closure scope.  Because JavaScript is single threaded we know that the variable cannot be re-assigned a second time before the callback is run.

Here you can see it working with a random timeout to simulate a http call.  The users and urls will be pair up correctly even though they execute async and in a random order.  (Try running this snippet multiple times to checkout the output is always consistent.)

```js
const sleep = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 1000));

let get;

async function login(username, callback) {
  console.log("logging in as", username);
  await sleep();
  get = async(url) => {
    await sleep();
    return `/${username}${url}`;
  };
  callback();
}

Promise.all([
  login("Alice", async() => {
    console.log(await get("/Active"));
  }),
  login("Bob", async() => {
    console.log(await get("/Build"));
  }),
  login("Colin", async() => {
    console.log(await get("/Compile"));
  }),
]);
```

The reason I don't recommend, is because this is very fragile code.  We have to be very careful to make sure that the `get` function is called only at the start of the callback.

If for example we call `sleep` then `get`, all bets are off.  We won't know which context `get` is using.

```js
const sleep = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 1000));

let get;

async function login(username, callback) {
  console.log("logging in as", username);
  await sleep();
  get = async(url) => {
    await sleep();
    return `/${username}${url}`;
  };
  callback();
}

Promise.all([
  login("Alice", async() => {
    await sleep();   // <-- The only change from the code above. DANGER
    console.log(await get("/Active"));
  }),
  login("Bob", async() => {
    await sleep();
    console.log(await get("/Build"));
  }),
  login("Colin", async() => {
    await sleep();
    console.log(await get("/Compile"));
  }),
]);
```

So while this is all very interesting and fun to code, I believe the best option is just to be explicit about the `obj` context you are using (as you already described in your question) and save yourself a headache.

Comment: That was an intressting solution. But I agree, it's way to magic to use in production code. My real problem has already been solved with obj. Mainly beacuse I think the code is more clear to read and understandable without deeper knowledge.